# generate CSR with SAN does not seem to work. on centos 8

Tags: openssl, centos, san

I have been trying to generate a CSR which includes a san of type **OtherName**.

the generated CSR does not seem to have the SAN field.

this is the configuration file:

```
distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name
[req_distinguished_name]
countryName                 = Country Name (2 letter code)
stateOrProvinceName         = State or Province Name (full name)
localityName               = Locality Name (eg, city)
organizationName           = Organization Name (eg, company)
commonName                 = Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)
[v3_req_client]
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
[alt_names]
otherName = 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.20.2.3;UTF8:user@localhost
```

I generate the CSR as this:

```
openssl req -out user.csr -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout private.key -config openssl.conf
```

but the resulting CSR does not have subjectaltNames field:

```
ertificate Request:
Data:
    Version: 1 (0x0)
    Subject: C = co, CN = user
    Subject Public Key Info:
        Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
            RSA Public-Key: (2048 bit)
            Modulus:
                00:df:19:be:1d:55:7d:f9:3a:29:e8:11:f6:ce:50:
                76:61:6b:5b:36:10:a7:b0:ac:99:83:0f:0f:a4:c6:
                1d:d7:c2:33:96:16:7b:5e:52:65:25:9f:e7:00:79:
                7d:b6:92:73:bb:5a:37:6d:ee:1f:18:09:71:bb:46:
                7c:65:95:1b:03:83:cf:ef:a8:79:0c:d0:bd:99:a5:
                34:5d:97:c3:29:d3:b6:59:4b:90:8c:57:65:aa:7d:
                9a:c3:7d:22:50:36:b0:e7:ba:c5:59:b0:f8:f0:90:
                26:4e:09:5b:5c:75:f2:1d:db:f4:aa:47:c0:65:b1:
                79:b6:10:7e:df:88:1f:9b:25:e4:20:69:09:36:8f:
                0e:ca:7c:2f:35:e2:7a:1e:c1:87:0f:20:0c:de:9e:
                94:17:8d:d3:4a:73:53:6d:88:d1:8b:e6:00:ca:e2:
                0c:99:ff:0b:6b:cb:5a:2d:e0:d0:27:5c:c0:66:ae:
                ce:b0:11:4a:9a:2c:30:f7:e2:bc:b0:2e:ac:eb:69:
                dd:db:9d:b5:84:85:24:80:d8:64:b5:c0:bc:d5:de:
                16:b7:0f:82:9c:8a:5b:9a:c8:21:40:20:42:cd:0b:
                64:55:55:76:56:11:af:b5:0b:3d:dc:81:28:61:d2:
                ff:c9:fd:43:2b:e3:1e:2e:c8:66:7b:21:14:4d:8d:
                45:c7
            Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
    Attributes:
        a0:00
Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
     23:b2:58:69:c3:93:b9:f4:45:2e:45:fa:af:e8:69:09:8d:3f:
     65:cb:6e:aa:3a:95:04:6a:21:81:02:c2:2f:fc:f4:98:cf:71:
     5a:4f:36:8e:e7:f5:09:a2:d3:8f:3d:49:55:6b:93:ed:bb:7e:
     78:c2:43:26:c1:6d:bf:9d:3c:29:3a:29:67:90:04:5a:fd:4f:
     9c:9d:7f:bb:98:67:ce:ab:66:be:0e:d5:af:4a:e5:fb:3b:72:
     c4:9c:cd:d7:f4:1c:81:2e:32:c5:8a:c5:d7:d7:9f:bc:1d:c9:
     51:94:0e:30:70:92:e1:ac:d4:d7:93:d8:9a:b8:5e:83:fc:cb:
     ab:6c:d4:f1:7f:70:96:f6:61:b8:48:14:d9:dc:1e:02:d3:ae:
     e5:90:1c:46:67:f3:99:2e:6e:4b:52:8e:71:0d:d2:31:2e:e6:
     0b:f9:88:b2:b8:a9:63:7a:5b:60:08:a4:ce:b8:5e:08:a7:cb:
     58:29:28:e4:30:85:2e:63:ae:bf:2b:51:ec:cc:29:96:16:72:
     20:80:d7:df:63:05:e8:f4:eb:59:d9:98:a2:f5:81:9f:7f:48:
     28:96:3f:bd:0f:e4:93:1a:d1:8d:53:d2:12:67:aa:52:3b:fe:
     f0:cf:c0:e5:7f:e4:96:16:c7:44:3f:5e:60:7a:f9:87:a8:e0:
     53:af:35:cd
```

but if a generate a certificate like this:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 3650 -newkey rsa:2048 -out test.pem -outform PEM -keyout test_key.pem -subj "/CN=user" -extensions v3_req_client -config openssl.conf -verbose
```

the resulting certificate has the subject alternative names: 
    ...
    X509v3 extensions:
        X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
            TLS Web Client Authentication
        X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
            othername:

but how i can just get a CSR with the SAN? what is missing in my csr request command to have it?

I am running CentOS Linux release 8.0.1905 (Core) with openssl version 1.1.1 FIPS

note I do not consider this to be a duplicate of: [Missing X509 extensions with an openssl-generated certificate](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/150078/missing-x509-extensions-with-an-openssl-generated-certificate) 
as the SAN is not even in the CSR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[v3_req_client]
extendedKeyUsage = clientAuth
subjectAltName = @alt_names
```

This section is not referenced anywhere. It will not be magically be used either. You have to explicitly provide what it should be used for, same as you did for `[req_distinguished_name]` with `distinguished_name = req_distinguished_name`:

```
req_extensions = v3_req_client
```

Comment: why it does not work when adding this to the command line: `-extensions v3_req_client`

Comment: @danidar: Because you have to use `-reqexts` instead. `-extensions` is for x509 extensions in the certificate.